# CodeIgniter 4 Routing - $ sign is not accepted in placeholder

Tags: php, routes, codeigniter-4

I have the following route in codegniter 4

```
$routes->add('/sample/(:any)/(:any)', 'Site/CountryController::addEdit/$1/$2');
```

`http://localhost/sample/1/1` gives me 404 error. However if I remove $ sign as follows, it works fine

```
$routes->add('/sample/(:any)/(:any)', 'Site/CountryController::addEdit/1/2');
```

Answer (score 1):

It works without dollar signs because you're in effect just always passing the integers `1` and `2` into the Controller method, regardless of what's regex'd with the placeholders.

I think your problem is that `http://localhost/sample/1/1` doesn't match the route `/sample/(:any)/(:any)`, it matches `/sample/(:any)`. The `(:any)` placeholder will literally glom onto anything, even multiple segments.

So defining a route as `.../(:any)/(:any)` is semantically pointless because the first `(:any)` is going to catch *everything*, leaving the second `(:any)` placeholder completely useless. As you've defined it now, the entire URI beyond `sample/` is being passed into `$1` via the first placeholder. You will never have a value to fill `$2` with.

It appears to me that you really want to be limiting this placeholder to `(:segment)`, not `(:any)`.